# Table DAU use of joins without any procedural in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can anyone help me with below solution to question in SQL query without using any loops or Procedural (using joins only)
Table DAU

Every day a player comes in the game, his/her user_id and date when he/she entered the game is   recorded in a table say Table DAU. It has two columns. 1. user_id 2. date

On a particular date, for a player there can be only one entry (No multiple entries on same day). However, the same player can come on different dates.

This table has data from 1/1/2015 (i.e January 1st) onwards. Below are sample entries from this table.

user_id date
1001    6/1/2015
1002    6/1/2015
1003    6/1/2015
1001    6/2/2015
1002    6/2/2015
1004    6/2/2015
1002    6/3/2015
1003    6/3/2015
1005    6/3/2015

Table Payment

Also, every time a player makes a payment in the game, his/her user_id and timestamp when he/she made the payment is recorded in a table, say Table Payment. It has two columns.       1. user_id 2. payment_timestamp

A player can make multiple payments on the same day and across days also.

Below are sample entries from this table.
user_id payment_timestamp
1001    6/1/2015 07:00
1001    6/1/2015 07:30
1002    6/1/2015 10:00
1001    6/2/2015 13:50
1002    6/2/2015 08:00
1004    6/2/2015 09:00
1003    6/3/2015 10:00
1005    6/3/2015  08:30

We define 90-Day Payer DAU for a particular date, say 6/1/2015 as follow:

Count (Player who came on 6/1/2015 and has made at least one payment in the game in last 90 days i.e from 3/4/2015 to 6/1/2015)

Similarly, 90-Day Payer DAU for 6/2/2015 wiil be:

Count (Players who came on 6/2/2015 and have made at least one payment in the game in last 90 days i.e from 3/5/2015 to 6/2/2015)

Question:

Using the DAU Table and Payment table, please write a SQL query to produce the below table. 
Date    90_Day_Payer DAU
6/1/2015
6/2/2015
6/3/2015
6/4/2015
6/5/2015
6/6/2015
6/7/2015

Exercise 2

We define D1 for a particular date, say 6/1/2015 as follow:

100* Count (Players who came on 6/1/2015 and who came on 6/2/2015) / Count (Players who came on 6/1/2015)

Similarly, we define D2 for a particular date, say 6/1/2015 as follow:

100* Count (Players who came on 6/1/2015 and who came on 6/3/2015) / Count (Players who came on 6/1/2015)

And so on for D3, D4, D5…..Dn

Question:

Using the DAU table explained in Exercise 1, please write a SQL query to produce the below table

`Date   Total Players   D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6  D7
6/1/2015    Total Number of Players who have come on 2015-06-01 D1 for 2015-06-01   D2 for 2015-06-01   D3 for 2015-06-01   D4 for 2015-06-01   D5 for 2015-06-01   D6 for 2015-06-01   D7 for 2015-06-01
6/2/2015    Total Number of Players who have come on 2015-06-02 D1 for 2015-06-02   D2 for 2015-06-03   D3 for 2015-06-02   D4 for 2015-06-02   D5 for 2015-06-02   D6 for 2015-06-02   D7 for 2015-06-02
6/3/2015    And so on
6/4/2015
6/5/2015
6/6/2015
6/7/2015

[if the above table is not clear you could refer below image link for table](https://i.stack.imgur.com)

Comment: What have you been able to do so far? Please don't dump your homework here with a plz send teh codez.

Comment: i have created both the tables payer table and dau table and got the answer to first question which is                                                      
         select dau.date_time,count(payer.user_id) from dau
   inner join payer on payer.user_id=dau.user_id
   where 
   date(payment_timestamp)<= (date(dau.date_time)+interval 90 day)
   group by dau.date_time

Comment: Please edit your question, comments are not for clarifications. Also please format your tables using code blocks. And again, show what parts you are able to do.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to exercise 1
select dau.date_time,count(payer.user_id) from dau
   inner join payer on payer.user_id=dau.user_id
   where 
   date(payment_timestamp)<= (date(dau.date_time)+interval 90 day)
   group by dau.date_time